# I'd like to have Characters only (no signs, numbers and spaces at all)

Tags: sqlite, autohotkey

It should be done with SQLite

just like this;

[image]

yes, I know, it is quite easy task, If I use **UDF**(User Define Function).

but, I have severe difficulty with it.

so, looking for another way (**no UDF** way) to achieve my goal.

Thanks

**for your reference,**

I leave a link that I have failed to make UDF (using AutoHotkey)

[SQLite/AutoHotkey, I have problem with Encoding of sqlite3_result_text return function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422168/sqlite-autohotkey-i-have-problem-with-encoding-of-sqlite3-result-text-return-fu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you could base the resolution on :-

```
WITH RECURSIVE eachchar(counter,rowid,c,rest) AS (
        SELECT 1,rowid,'',mycolumn AS rest FROM mytable
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT counter+1,rowid,substr(rest,1,1),substr(rest,2) FROM eachchar WHERE length(rest) > 0 LIMIT 100
    )
SELECT group_concat(c,'') AS mycolumn, myothercolumn, mycolumn AS original
FROM eachchar JOIN mytable ON eachchar.rowid = mytable.rowid 
WHERE length(c) > 0 
    AND (
        unicode(c) BETWEEN unicode('a') AND unicode('z') 
        OR unicode(c) BETWEEN unicode('A') AND unicode('Z')
    )
GROUP BY rowid;
```

## Demo :-

Perhaps consider the following :-

```
/* Create the Test Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mycolumn TEXT, myothercolumn);
/* Add the Testing data */
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    ('123-abc_"D E F()[]{}~`!@#$%^&*-+=|\?><<:;''','A')
    ,('123-xyz_"X Y Z()[]{}~`!@#$%^&*-+=|\?><<:;''','B')
    ,('123-abc_"A B C()[]{}~`!@#$%^&*-+=|\?><<:;''','C')
;

/* split each character thenconcatenat only the required characters*/
WITH RECURSIVE eachchar(counter,rowid,c,rest) AS (
        SELECT 1,rowid,'',mycolumn AS rest FROM mytable
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT counter+1,rowid,substr(rest,1,1),substr(rest,2) FROM eachchar WHERE length(rest) > 0 LIMIT 100
    )
SELECT group_concat(c,'') AS mycolumn, myothercolumn, mycolumn AS original
FROM eachchar JOIN mytable ON eachchar.rowid = mytable.rowid 
WHERE length(c) > 0 
    AND (
        unicode(c) BETWEEN unicode('a') AND unicode('z') 
        OR unicode(c) BETWEEN unicode('A') AND unicode('Z')
    )
GROUP BY rowid;
/* Cleanup Test Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
```

This results in :-

[image]

Comment: Wow.. looks quite advanced (I am a beginner). Thanks Lot, I will take a look at it and execute it for sure with time.

Comment: @KitaNagoya you might want to have a look at [The Simplest SQLite Common Table Expression Tutorial](https://blog.expensify.com/2015/09/25/the-simplest-sqlite-common-table-expression-tutorial/). Oh and the `LIMIT 1000` was  a *just in case* limiter, so you may want to increase it or do away with it as the `length(rest)` should be sufficient to stop the recursion.

Comment: Yap, I am a beginner so, your link sould be very good guide for my long and painful journey. Thanks again.