# Too many functions, how to reduce it?

Tags: sqlite, autohotkey

**[EDIT]**

I am writing codes with SQLite in AutoHotkey(minor Windows language).
But, I have problem with UDF(User Define Function) in the middle of it.

So, **I can not use RegExp**..OMG. Therefore, I am having VERY VERY painful time now.

This post of mine.. should be VERY easy, if I used RegExp. Should be solved in 3 minutes.

Now I am struggling 3 more days - I am beginner in SQLite.

Here, I have posted SQLite help for RegeExp, actually RegExp part is fine, I have problem with CallBack function's alien return language.

[SQLite/AutoHotkey, I have problem with Encoding of sqlite3_result_text return function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422168/sqlite-autohotkey-i-have-problem-with-encoding-of-sqlite3-result-text-return-fu)

I have posted similar help post earlier. And got a nice answer.

[I'd like to have Characters only (no signs, numbers and spaces at all)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453369/id-like-to-have-characters-only-no-signs-numbers-and-spaces-at-all)

**Remove signs, numbers and spaces**

[image]

```
"abc D E F 0123456789  !@#$%^&*-+  _<>()[]{}~  =|\?:;''`.,  /"
```

**But**.. unfortunately I have failed to use it (failed to understand it, my bad)   **And**.. got slightly different ideas too - considering different Languages not only ASCII-English but also Chinese/Japanese/Korean too).

So, I wrote quite straightforward method, like this;

```
UPDATE myTable SET myCOL = lower(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(myCOL
, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', '')
, '!', ''), '@', ''), '#', ''), '$', ''), '%', ''), '^', ''), '&', ''), '*', ''), '-', ''), '+', ''));

UPDATE myTable SET myCOL = replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(myCOL
, '_', ''), '<', ''), '>', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''), '{', ''), '}', ''), '~', '')
, '=', ''), '|', ''), '\', ''), '?', ''), ':', ''), ';', ''), '''', ''), '`', ''), '.', ''), ',', ''), ' ', '');
```

It has 40 plain functions, one lower case and remove space - in total 42 functions.

Query works fine, I have confirmed.

Looks... beginnish.

Any better ideas?

Thanks..

Comment: I am not sure with sqlite but may be try regex?

Comment: Right, you are quite right. I will [EDIT] my main post, as your comment.